# Java Mongodb not authorized to

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I am coding in java and to implement persistence for my game model and players I was hoping to create and use a mongo database.  I am not using any authentication, but mongodb is throwing an error that insists that I am not authorized to do anything.

What would cause the program to think that authentication is necessary and how can I fix this?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException:
Command failed with error 13: 
'not authorized on Catan2 to execute command 

{
    insert: "Players",
    ordered: true,
    documents: [ { _id: 20, Login: "{"username":"un","password":"p","ID":20}" } ]
}'

on server 127.0.0.1:27017.
The full response is 
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on Catan2 to execute command 
        { 
            insert: \"Players\",
            ordered: true,
            documents: [ { _id: 20, Login: \"{\"username\":\"un\",\"password\":\"p\",\"ID\":20}\" } ] 
}", 
"code" : 13 }
```

I have included my code below to show the steps that I am taking.

```
import server.plugincode.iplugin.IPersistencePlugin;
import server.plugincode.iplugin.IPlayerDAO;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import shared.jsonobject.Login;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
public class MongoPersistencePlugin implements IPersistencePlugin {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private PlayerDAO Players;
    private DB mdb;

    public MongoPersistencePlugin()
    {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase mdb = mongoClient.getDatabase("Catan2");

        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        gson.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();
        String info = gson.create().toJson(new Login("un", "p", 20));

        Document test = new Document("_id", 20).append("Login", info);
        mdb.getCollection("Players").insertOne(test);
        mdb.getCollection("Players").drop();

        Players = new PlayerDAO(mdb);

        // Games = new GameDAO(mdb);
       // Commands = new CommandDAO(mdb);
        //   clear();
    }
}
```

I am using Mongodb 3.0, Java 8 and am working on a Windows laptop if that helps.

Comment: Do you have [security.authorization](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization) option in your configuration file ?

Comment: If I have a configuration file, it was magically created and I don't know where it hid itself at.

Comment: How do you start mongodb ? Also try connecting via the [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/#the-mongo-shell) and do an insert. If you are getting an error, please post both the error from the shell, and the mongod server log.